# Linux-x64 glibc: Why does Feb 1 come before Jan 31?

Tags: c++, c, linux, glibc, mktime

When you call mktime(), Feb 1 seems to come before Jan 31.  Why is this? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in glibc?

Here's the code:

```
struct tm tm;
time_t tt;

memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
tm.tm_year = 2011;
tm.tm_mon = 1;
tm.tm_mday = 31;
tm.tm_hour = 11;
tm.tm_min = 41;
tm.tm_sec = 28;
tm.tm_isdst = 0;
tt = mktime(&tm);

printf("Time now %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d (%s) = %lu\n",
    tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, tm.tm_zone, tt);


memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
tm.tm_year = 2011;
tm.tm_mon = 2;
tm.tm_mday = 1;
tm.tm_hour = 1;
tm.tm_min = 1;
tm.tm_sec = 1;
tm.tm_isdst = 0;
tt = mktime(&tm);

printf("Time now %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d (%s) = %lu\n",
    tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, tm.tm_zone, tt);
```

And here's the output:

```
Time now 2011-2-3 11:41:28 (PST) = 61257325288
Time now 2011-2-1 1:1:1 (PST) = 61257114061
```

Note that the original intention was to compare two time_t's.  This issue causes the first date/time to appear to be later than the second, which is obviously a bit of a problem.

This is just compiled with "gcc test.c" and run with "./a.out" on Ubuntu 9.10, gcc version 4.4.1 (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu8),  libc-2.10.1-0ubuntu15

On a 32-bit system the results are as expected - i.e. completely different to the 64 bit result!

Would anyone care to confirm/refute this result and/or give some insight into what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tm_mon is zero-based, so you attempted to set February 31st, which got normalized.  Here's a link to the definition of [mktime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/).

Comment: Simply speaking, February 31 (which is actually March 3 or March 2) is later than March 1.

Comment: Thanks Jim - bit of a duh moment ;)  Not sure how I missed that after RTFM'ing multiple times!

Comment: @Paul - We all have those moments -- I've had more than I care to remember :-)

Comment: This has nothing to do with 32 vs 64 bit.  mktime normalizes out-of-range dates so if you set the month to February (1) and the day to 31 and then call mktime() the result will be March 3rd (in a non-leap year; March 2nd in a leap year).

Answer (score 3):

> Why does Feb 1 come before Jan 31?

Incorrect assignments to `struct tm` members.

---

**`.tm_mon` is zero based**

`.tm_mon` is zero based[@Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879440/2410359).

```
// tm.tm_mon = 1;
tm.tm_mon = 1 - 1; // For January
```

**`.tm.tm_year` is 1900 based**

```
// tm.tm_year = 2011;
tm.tm_year = 2011 - 1900;
```

**`time_t` print specifier**

`"%ld"` is not certainly the matching specifier for `time_t`, thus incurring *undefined behavior* (UB). `time_t` might not not even be an integer type.  Recommend a cast to a wide signed type or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066562/2410359).  Note that `tt = mktime(&tm)` returns a -1 value on error, so useful to see -1 and not an unsigned value.

```
// printf("%lu\n", tt);
printf("%lld\n", (long long) tt);
```

**.tm_isdst**

`mktime()` operates on *local time*.  `tm.tm_isdst = 0;` asserts the time stamp is *standard time* (reasonable for [PST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone) about January).  Had this code been run in a timezone with *daylight* time in January (e.g. [Wellington](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/new-zealand/wellington)), the reported `tm.tm_hour` may differ from expectations.  Usually best to let `mktime()` deduce `.tm_isdst`.  Otherwise finding the difference between timestamps (OP's higher goal) may shift an hour unexpectedly when spanning a DST change.

```
// tm.tm_isdst = 0;
tm.tm_isdst = -1;  // DST information is not available, mktime will adjust.
tt = mktime(&tm)
```

Comment: Good clean up -- great summertime project where we lack the normal flood of students...