# Format specifier to print time(0) in C

Tags: c, time, types

We can declare a variable to hold the current time from the system using:

```
time_t now = time(0);
```

`time(0)` can also be use in generating random values:

```
#define SEED time(0);
srand((unsigned int )SEED);
```

**My question is:** What exactly is `time(0)`. By default is it in milliseconds with type `long`? If I want to print out the value of `time(0)`, can I use `"%d"` to print it out? (Sicne `printf()` requires us to pass in the type it requires, but how can I know what is the type of `time(0)` ?).

If it is of type `time_t`, what format specifier should I use in printf?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to

Comment: This page also explains how to handle the return value: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/ It boils down to needing to use functions to convert it to a `tm` structure.

Comment: Read about [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) & [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) & [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Answer (score 5):

`time_t` is defined by C standard, C11, 7.27.1/3 as:

> [...]    which are real types capable of representing times;

That means it could be int, long, unsigned long, double or any other real type. Basically it's an implementation's choice. Similarly, it doesn't define what units `time_t` returns either, C11, 7.27.2.4/3:

> The time function  returns  the  implementation’s best  approximation 
>   to  the  current calendar  time. The  value (time_t)(-1) is  returned 
>   if  the  calendar  time  is  not available.  If timer is not a null
>   pointer, the return value is also assigned to the object it points to.

You'll have to read what your implementation says. The glibc implementation I have on my Linux says, the unit returned by time_t is in seconds. So you could convert it to `uintmax_t` and print:

```
time_t tvalue = time(0);
printf("%ju", (uintmax_t)tvalue);
```

Or you could use [difftime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/difftime.3.html) which returns a `double` as difference between two `time_t` values so that you don't have to worry about the underlying type of `time_t`.

Comment: I'd use `intmax_t` rather than `uintmax_t`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't define what type `time_t` is; it only has to be a real type capable of representing times. It could be an integer type or a floating-point type (it can't be complex -- fortunately). And it's not necessarily a number of seconds, or milliseconds, or *any* simple units. It could in principle use ranges of bits to represent months, seconds, days, hours, minutes, and years *in that order* in binary coded decimal. The most common representation is a 32-bit or 64-bit signed integer representing seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

If you want a completely portable way to print a `time_t` value, you can detect what kind of type `time_t` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    printf("At the sound of the tone, the time will be ... \a");

    if ((time_t)1 / 2 != 0) {
        // time_t is a floating-point type; convert to long double
        printf("%Lf\n", (long double)now);
    }
    else if ((time_t)-1 > (time_t)0) {
        // time_t is an unsigned integer type
        printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)now);
    }
    else {
        // time_t is a signed integer type
        printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)now);
    }
}
```

This assumes a C99 or later implementation. If you're stuck with a pre-C99 implementation that doesn't support `<stdint.h>` and/or the `%ju` and `%jd` formats (which you can detect this by testing `__STDC_VERSION__`), you can convert to `long` or `unsigned long` rather than `[u]intmax_t`. (MinGW probably won't handle printing a `long double` value correctly, but MinGW uses a signed integer type for `time_t` so that's not an issue.)

This will print a raw value that isn't meaningful unless you happen to know how `time_t` is represented (both what type it is *and* how it represents the current time). On my system, the current time is `1416589039`, which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (a very common representation).

If you want to know *what time it is* rather than the raw value returned by the `time()` function, you should use the functions in `<time.h>` to generate a human-readable representation of the current time. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    char s[100];
    strftime(s, sizeof s, "%F %H:%M:%S %Z", localtime(&now));
    printf("The time is now %s\n", s);
}
```

which prints (at the moment on my system):

```
The time is now 2014-11-21 08:57:19 PST
```

Comment: Was just thinking about this `if ((time_t) ...` approach and then you fine answer pops up.  Minor BTW: Cannot code work without the 2nd cast in `((time_t)-1 > 0)`?

Comment: @chux: Probably, but IMHO it's clearer with the cast. And it means I don't have to think about the case where `time_t` is narrower than `int` (not sure it matters, but as I said I don't have to think about it).

Answer (score 1):

On most system time_t is define on the same number of bit than integer and is always positive.

In this case you can use:

```
 printf("time: %u", (unsigned int) time(0));
```

Comment: don't use `%d` to `printf` an `unsigned int`, that's undefined behaviour. `%u` would be correct.

Comment: Incorrect. `time(0)` returns `(time_t)-1` if it fails for some reason, and the standard says *only* that `time_t` is an arithmetic type capable of representing times. On the system I'm typing this comment on, `sizeof (int) == 4` and `sizeof (time_t) == 8`.

Comment: The behavior of the `printf` is well defined *if* `time_t` is an integer type. If the value is negative or exceeds `UINT_MAX`, the output won't be the actual value, but it will be adjusted consistently. If `time_t` is a floating-point type and the value is negative or exceeds `UINT_MAX`, the behavior of the conversion is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, standard does not specifies what time_t is. If you want to be sure to use it in a portable way, first convert it to long and then print it as a long. That way your program won't suffer the Year 2038 problem even if 32 bits architectures are still available at that time :-) ...

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
long lt = (t > 0) ? t : (unsigned int) t;
printf("%ld", lt);
```

It should work for time_t being a 32 bits signed of insigned integer or a 64 bit integer. My formule will break when time_t will be a negative 64 bits integer, but contact me at that time and I should then be wise enough to find a better solution :-)

EDIT :

As noted by chux this is bad if int is only 16 bits. Here is a robust even if ugly way

```
union {
    long l;
    unsigned char[1] c;
} ul;
time_t t = time(NULL);
ul.l = 0;
ul.c[0] = 255;
if (ul.l < 0) { /* endianness test */
    ul.l = 0;
    memcpy(&ul.l, t&, sizeof(time_t));
}
else {
    ul.l = 0;
    memcpy(&ul.l + sizeof(long) - sizeof(time_t), &t, sizeof(time_t));
}
printf("%lu", (unsigned long) ul.l);
```

It should work in any configuration provided `sizeof(long)>=sizeof(time_t)`

EDIT 2:

chux's proposal seems to work on any *reasonable* cases. There are certainly pathological cases where it could break but on a normal implementation

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
long lt = (t > 0) ? t : t * 1u;
printf("%ld", lt);
```

should give correct result.

Comment: Why cast `t` to `unsigned` instead of `unsigned long`?

Comment: @chux : because at least on MSVC, when I directly convert a negative short to a unsigned long, the actual conversion is short -> long (extending sign) -> unsigned long, and all high order bits get value 1 when I want them to keep value 0.

Comment: I suppose `time_t` _could_ be a `short` - never have come across that.  I have come across in 2014 where `unsigned` is 16-bit and `time_t` is 32-bit so `(unsigned int) t` would truncate.

Comment: @chux : you are right, my formula breaks if `int` is only 16 bits :-( . I wanted to pass when `int` and `time_t` are both 32 bits and long is 64 bits.

Comment: Maybe `long lt = (t > 0) ? t : t * 1u;` to avoid truncation?

Comment: @chux would certainly be nicer than my edit ! But what says the standard about an operation between signed and unsigned types ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65389/discussion-between-chux-and-serge-ballesta).

Answer (score 0):

looking into the header file(s) for the time function, 
you will see that the parameter can be one of two things NULL or address of time_t variable.

The time() function results for both the parameter and the returned value is the elapsed time, in seconds, since the epoch (currently Jan 1, 1970 00:00 am UTC.) The sizing of the value (on older systems) was 4 bytes (32bits).  with recent RTC (RealTimeClock) hardware available, the value 'may' be 8 bytes (64bits) .  in any case the value in is seconds since the epoch.

The 4 byte time values will overflow in 2038, so efforts are being made to either 
    1) make the time value a larger size or 
    2) shift the epoch time forward to Jan 1 2000 00:00 am. 
       ( a temporary fix when using older hardware )

the changing of the time values to 8  bytes is the current preferred method.

here is a specific quote from google:

"At 03:14:08 UTC on 19 January 2038, 32-bit versions of the Unix time stamp will cease to work"  to paraphase the rest of the quote: the 32 bit value will overflow.

The functions that handle time, like localtime() strtotime(). etc and the related structs, like tm, are setup to use what ever the system they are running on is returning from the time() function.

All the processing of the value from the time function should be done using the available functions rather than handling the raw value.