# Why is my second time_t variable not shown correctly

Tags: c++, time-t

I would like to measure how long a particular operation takes, therefore I've written the following piece of code:

```
for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 <= 10; counter2++) { // I'll do the test 10 times,
                                                     // for having reliable results

    time_t ltime;
    time(&ltime); // What's the time at the beginning?

    for (counter = 0; counter <= 1000000; counter++) {
        Do_Something();
    }

    time_t ltime2;
    time(&ltime2); // What's the time after having launched Do_Something()?
    printf("Times:First=[%d], Second=[%d]\n", ltime, ltime2);

}
```

I'm expecting something like:

```
Times: First=[1559574983], Second=[1559574985]
Times: First=[1559574990], Second=[1559574999]
```

Instead I get this:

```
Times: First=[1559574983], Second=[0]
Times: First=[1559574990], Second=[0]
```

I've already debugged, and `ltime2` seems to be correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `time_t` is a `typedef` for an unspecified type, so it's not clear what format string you should use for your platform. Use `std::cout` instead of you want a more portable solution.

Comment: Alternatively, use [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) facilities.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Please answer in the answer section where it can be peer reviewed

Comment: "_for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 <= 10; counter2++) { // I'll do the test 10 times_" - This actually performs the test 11 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format `"%d"` is not the right one in your case, but you don't have to take care of the type supporting `time_t` just replace

> ```
>  printf("Times:First=[%d], Second=[%d]\n", ltime, ltime2);
> ```

by

```
std::cout << "Times:First=[" << ltime << "], Second=[" << ltime2 << "]" << std::endl;
```

---

If for an obscure reason you *really* want to use a C *printf* as proposed by @*Lightness Races in Orbit 3* in a remark you can convert the value to an other type (hopping enough long) and use the format compatible to that type, see [Format specifier to print time(0) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27058756/560648)

Comment: And the reason the first "works" is probably something like it's only read the top half of the first argument (and let's presume that the bottom half is zero), due to the dodgy format specifier

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes to have that behavior means the size of `time_t` is not the size of an _int_. I edit my answer with the information from your link

Comment: You could improve your answer by also mentioning the *correct* format string to use for `printf`. OP *may* have good reason to prefer `printf` over `cout` or may just be curious.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Unforts, there isn't one (see linked answer) - I do agree this should be mentioned

Comment: This should be reasonably portable: `printf("Times:First=[%jd], Second=[%jd]\n", static_cast<std::intmax_t>(ltime), static_cast<std::intmax_t>(ltime2));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, but it is quite masochist to do all that effort when `ostream <<` does that gracefully ^^

Comment: @bruno :-) I totally agree. I just put it there since hoping for `long` to be enough may not work on some platforms. `intmax_t` with its `j` modfifier will probably work with all conforming compilers. Unless `time_t` is unsigned... Hmm ... I may need to rethink this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick replies.
Just for the record, hereby the final solution I'm using (combining the [mentioned other Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27058756/560648) and `difftime()` function):

```
printf("First=[%ju], Second=[%ju], Difference=[%f]\n", (uintmax_t) ltime, 
                                                       (uintmax_t) ltime2, 
                                                       difftime(ltime2, ltime));
```